# Remapping key names in a list of dictionaries

Tags: python

What is a pythonic way to remap each dictionary key in a list of identically-keyed dictionaries to different key names? E.g.,

```
[{'type_id': 6, 'type_name': 'Type 1'}, {'type_id': 12, 'type_name': 'Type 2'}]
```

must transform into

```
[{'type': 6, 'name': 'Type 1'}, {'type': 12, 'name': 'Type 2'}]
```

(I need to do the transformation in order to match an output specification for an API I'm working on.)

Comment: "best" by what measure? There are lots of ways to do this. Easy to read? Low memory? Fast?

Comment: Good point.  How about "most pythonic"? :) So probably leaning toward easy-to-read, in the fewest lines of code. I find that typically when I'm faced with this type of scenario, there is usually some cool or interesting built-in python functionality that makes it happen, rather than writing a brute-force loop, although I'm open to that. The list will typically be less than 20 dictionaries so memory and speed aren't as big of an issue for me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/644178/how-do-i-re-map-python-dict-keys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just use a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

```
>>> d = [{'type_id': 6, 'type_name': 'Type 1'}, {'type_id': 12, 'type_name': 'Type 2'}]
>>> print [{'type':x['type_id'],'name':x['type_name']} for x in d]
[{'type': 6, 'name': 'Type 1'}, {'type': 12, 'name': 'Type 2'}]
>>>
```

Comment: I'm always amazed at how much you can do with list comprehensions.

Answer (score 8):

Python >= 2.7 (using a [dict comprehension](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/)):

```
transform = {"type_id": "type", "type_name": "name"}
new_list = [{transform[k]: v for k, v in d.items()} for d in old_list]
```

Python >= 2.4 (using the [dict](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict) constructor):

```
transform = {"type_id": "type", "type_name": "name"}
new_list = [dict((transform[k], v) for k, v in d.items()) for d in old_list]
```

Comment: The nested dictionary comprehension inside of a list comprehension is a very powerful & flexible construct for doing transforms.  I would definitely consider it for a more complex case, but given the simplicity of my needs, I like Joran's a bit better since it's more straightforward.

Answer (score 3):

How about inplace modifications?

```
>>> transform = {"type_id": "type", "type_name": "name"}    
>>> for D in L:
    for k,k_new in transform.items():
        D[k_new] = D.pop(k)             
>>> L
[{'type': 6, 'name': 'Type 1'}, {'type': 12, 'name': 'Type 2'}]
```

---

Or even better:

```
>>> for D in L:
    for k,k_new in transform.items():
        value = D.pop(k,None)
        if value is not None:
            D[k_new] = value
```

Answer (score 1):

The new-user-friendly, easy-to-read way:

```
>>> list2 = []
>>> for d in list1:
...     x = dict()
...     for k,v in d.iteritems():
...        x[k.split('_')[1]] = v
...     list2.append(x)
...
>>> list2
[{'name': 'Type 1', 'id': 6}, {'name': 'Type 2', 'id': 12}]
```