# get keyerror when trying to remap the keys of a dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to remap or change the keys of a dictionary to 1,2,3,..., since the keys themselves are a bit complicated. Following this post, [How do I re-map python dict keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/644178/how-do-i-re-map-python-dict-keys)
this is what I did.

```
tmp=0
for keys in population.items():
        tmp+=1
        population[tmp]=population.pop(keys)
```

However, I got keyerrors, which generally means the keys does not exist. Can anyone help me please? PS. I did a random sampling with respect to the items of the dictionary population. So I am not exactly sure about what the keys of the dictionary population are.

EDIT: I changed the code. Then it works for a small data set, while it does not quite work for a large one. I added the following code.

```
for keys, vs in population.items():
        print str(keys)+ "corresponding to" + str(vs)

Here is what I got:
1024corresponding to10
7corresponding to2
855corresponding to4
13corresponding to310
686corresponding to6
22corresponding to172
24corresponding to214
25corresponding to62
26corresponding to18
28corresponding to9
29corresponding to435
30corresponding to210
32corresponding to243
34corresponding to450
859corresponding to8
37corresponding to1
689corresponding to3
43corresponding to53
46corresponding to8
47corresponding to2
48corresponding to7
52corresponding to254
54corresponding to441
820corresponding to3
57corresponding to19
59corresponding to9
61corresponding to3
63corresponding to1
65corresponding to1
66corresponding to6
(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0)corresponding to7
68corresponding to46842
73corresponding to8
74corresponding to513
75corresponding to52
866corresponding to10
79corresponding to5
80corresponding to712
81corresponding to1
82corresponding to118
83corresponding to15
84corresponding to9
87corresponding to1
88corresponding to7
868corresponding to24
93corresponding to133
94corresponding to9
97corresponding to355
98corresponding to10
99corresponding to9
101corresponding to1
103corresponding to93
114corresponding to3
702corresponding to5
119corresponding to1
121corresponding to1
123corresponding to5
124corresponding to3
125corresponding to3
819corresponding to5
127corresponding to8
131corresponding to137
133corresponding to3
138corresponding to145
139corresponding to3
142corresponding to14
145corresponding to3
147corresponding to6
149corresponding to6
(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 0)corresponding to1
```

EDIT EDIT: I wanted to change all the tuples to numbers to denote the keys of the population dictionary. But after I made the change, and then print out all the keys and values, it still gave me tuples, as you can see from the print out.

Comment: What does `population` look like?

Comment: Note that `.items()` does not return a list of keys.  It returns a list of `(key, value)` tuples.  See `pydoc dict` for more information.

Comment: @michaelpri, population maps tuples to an integer.

Comment: I don't see any code in the answers to the linked question that do what you're doing here.  Look back at those answers and do what they did.

Comment: @larsks, yes. I see. However, does this affect what is going on here?

Comment: If you're just wanting access by index, `population.values()` will give you a list which you can access by `[0]`, `[1]`, etc.

Comment: You do **not** want to remap, but create a list from a dict. These are different data types. Please be more precise in your questions.

Comment: @Olaf, thanks for mentioning that.

Comment: Note that a dict does not maintain a specific ordering of its entries. Therfore, an item appended to a dict is not guaranted to be the last item read from an iteration over the dict. If you need that, you might have a look at `collections.OrderedDict`

Comment: @Olaf, thanks. I have been tried to search for dict.items(), but this is not exactly what I want. Maybe can modify it a bit.

Comment: In your edit, could you clarify what you mean by "does not work". In what sense? Error (which, traceback)? Semantics? Whatelse?

Comment: @Olaf, thanks for your reply. I simply print out the keys and values (see the edit). But it is not what I expected.

Comment: I added an answer. Would be nice if you comment on that (really curious).

Answer (score 1):

`dict.items()` returns a list of key/value pairs (which is why you get the `KeyError` error when trying to lookup the dict for the tuple instead of the key), what you need is just the keys:

```
tmp = 0
for k in population.keys():
    tmp += 1
    population[tmp] = population.pop(k)
```

**EDIT**: Since `for k in dict` iterates through a generator of keys, you might get weird behavior when modifying the keys at the same time. To avoid this, I modified the code to use `population.keys()` instead which returns a list of keys (in python2) instead of a keys generator. In python3 `dict.keys()` returns a view object instead which should be safe as long as the dict's size isn't changed during iteration (safer to iterate over `list(population)`)

Comment: Actually, .in Python3 this returns a View object, not a generator.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `.items()` and this should work.  As larsks says, `items` returns tuples, but you just want the keys.

Answer (score 0):

I still don't undestand this. You have a dict, then you pack all values into a list. By this you already loose all relation between key and value. What would be the purpose for the dict then?

However, to get a list of all values as you seem to want (but also need?), you just do:

```
my_list = list(my_dict.values())
```

No need for a loop or anything else.