# Open a CSV file, skip to the 6th line, write the data with different headers to a different file, line by line

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

Edit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/644314/8520561 did not solve the problem, either because I drop a key, the code is wrong, I don't understand it, or all of the above.

I have edited the end of the script below, to show what gave me the correct answer.

As an exercise in forcing myself to learn python, I want to use it to create something useful. I am trying to do it as properly as possible within python. No cheating allowed, like using Unix command line tools to avoid a few lines of python.

I want to open a CSV file, and starting from the 7th line of the input file, write it to a different CSV file with different headers. The 6th line defines the input headers. I have assumed they are always the same.

The input headers are in CS_headers, and the output headers are in YNAB_headers

```
# Define the headers for the bank statement input file
CS_headers = ['Booking Date', 'Text', 'Debit', 'Credit', 'Balance']
# Define the headers for the YNAB output file
YNAB_headers = ['Date', 'Payee', 'Memo', 'Inflow', 'Outflow']
```

I want to map

`'Booking Date'` → `'Date'`
`'Text'` → `'Payee'`
`'Debit'` → `'Outflow'`
`'Credit'` → `'Inflow'`
Drop `'Balance'` from the output

and sometimes

inject something into the `'Memo'` field.

The script output

```
$ ./cs_statement.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./cs_statement.py", line 52, in <module>
    statementwriter.writerow(row)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/csv.py", line 155, in writerow
    return self.writer.writerow(self._dict_to_list(rowdict))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/csv.py", line 151, in _dict_to_list
    + ", ".join([repr(x) for x in wrong_fields]))
ValueError: dict contains fields not in fieldnames: 'Booking Date', 'Debit', 'Balance', 'Text', 'Credit'
```

The first few lines of the input file.

```
$ $ head -8 statement.csv | cat -n
 1  Created on  30.06.2019 12:14:06 CEST
 2  Bookings
 3  Account,"Private account Bonviva Silver,CH72 0483 5028 1234 5678 0,John Doe, Swisstown"
 4  Balance,"CHF 37,924.81"
 5  Booking Entries from 05.07.2018 - 30.06.2019
 6  Booking Date,Text,Debit,Credit,Balance
 7  28.06.2019,"Payment domestic - ISR ,Salt Mobile SA ,AID5c9fdb2ae4744b9ba7ad22afbd16b17d,Salt Mobile SA,Rue du Caudray 4 1020 Renens 1,UBS Switzerland AG,Bahnhofstrasse 45 8098 Zürich CH ",19.00,,37924.81
 8  28.06.2019,"Payment domestic - ISR ,Mortgage Q2 2019 ,DNCS-20190615-IXN0-TXN0,Mortgage Q2 2019,SP-29312538-0,SWISS LIFE AG,ZUERICH ",806.25,,
```

The script as it is at the moment.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3

import csv
import re


# Credit Scheiß's idea of a CSV file includes:
# 1 the first 3 characters are non-ASCII
# 2 the CSV headers are on line 6
# 3 the last line is a totals line
def skip_lines(handle, numlines):
    for i in range(0, numlines):
        handle.readline()


lines_to_skip = 5
in_filename = 'bankstatement.csv'
out_filename = 'bankstatement.YNAB.csv'

# Define the headers for the bank statement input file
CS_headers = ['Booking Date', 'Text', 'Debit', 'Credit', 'Balance']
# Define the headers for the YNAB output file
YNAB_headers = ['Date', 'Payee', 'Memo', 'Inflow', 'Outflow']

# open the file and skip to the heaeder line
statement_infile_handle = open(in_filename, 'r', newline='')
skip_lines(statement_infile_handle, lines_to_skip)

# what kind of CSV file am I?
dialect = csv.Sniffer().sniff(statement_infile_handle.read(10240))
statement_infile_handle.seek(0)
skip_lines(statement_infile_handle, lines_to_skip)

# define a CSV reader object to, er, read the file
statementreader = csv.DictReader(statement_infile_handle,
                                 fieldnames=CS_headers, restkey='',
                                 dialect=dialect)

# define a CSV writer, so I stand a chance of getting at the headers
statement_outfile_handle = open(out_filename, 'w', newline='')
# statementwriter = csv.writer(statement_outfile_handle)
statementwriter = csv.DictWriter(statement_outfile_handle,
                                 fieldnames=YNAB_headers, restval='',
                                 dialect=dialect)
statementwriter.writeheader()

# This part
#    for row in statementreader:
#        statementwriter.writerow(row)
#
# was replaced with this, to solve the problem.
keymap = {'Booking Date': 'Date', 'Text': 'Payee',
         'Debit': 'Outflow', 'Credit': 'Inflow'}
for row in statementreader:
outrow = {keymap[key]: value for key, value in row.items() if key in
          keymap}
statementwriter.writerow(outrow)
```

Comment: I suspect the Exception is because the reader has different field names than the writer. You said you wanted to map original field names to new names. Have you tried making a new dictionary for each row then writing it, e.g.`... newrow['Payee'] = oldrow['Text'] ...`

Comment: Also: `lines_to_skip = 5` --> `lines_to_skip = 6`

Comment: `output_row = YNAB_headers
for row in statementreader:
    output_row['Date'] = row['Booking Date']`

won't compile: 

`$ ./cs_statement.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./cs_statement.py", line 51, in <module>
    output_row['Date'] = row['Booking Date']
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`

Comment: `for row in statementreader:
    output_row['Date'] = row['Booking Date']`
gives this compilation error:
`./cs_statement.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./cs_statement.py", line 51, in <module>
    output_row['Date'] = row['Booking Date']
NameError: name 'output_row' is not defined`

Comment: Did you look at the excepted answer for the possible duplicate? You will have a refinement because you are dropping a key.

Comment: I checked the possible dupe, but the code I pasted in generated a compilation error. So either the code is wrong, or my comprehension of it is wrong, or both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to map old keys to new keys, when you say to yourself `I want to map something`, think dictionary. You need to make a new dictionary for each row.

```
...
newkeys = {'Booking Date':'Date','Text':'Payee',
           'Debit':'Outflow','Credit':'Inflow'}

for row in statementreader:
    newrow = {newkeys[key]:value for key,value in row.items() if key in newkeys}
    statementwriter.writerow(newrow)
```

---

Which could also be written:

```
for row in statementreader:
    newrow = {}
    for key,value in row.items():
        if key in newkeys:
            newrow[newkeys[key]] = value
    statementwriter.writerow(newrow)
```

or

```
for row in statementreader:
    newrow = {}
    for key,value in row.items():
        try:
            newrow[newkeys[key]] = value
        except KeyError:
            pass
    statementwriter.writerow(newrow)
```